# Is there any way to deal with Minio file by sql-based statements?

Tags: minio

I am new on Minio and object based databases.
I know that there is S3 select API but I want to add a new row or update a specific row in CSV file in Minio without need to download it and upload again.
Is there any way to do it?
In another words, I want to use sql based statements(insert/update) on a file stored in Minio.

Answer (score 0):

You can only change Databases with SQL, it can only Import and Export CSVs so that they are usable for the Database. The Answer for now would then be a no. The easiest way you could achieve editing this csv would be to write a Script which either:

- Connects to the Database and Changes the File in the Databases
  Directory.
- Downloads the File to edit it locally and then upload it again.